# Twitter Topsy API results

Tags: api, twitter, topsy

We are trying to analyze the twitter Topsy API for twitter searches for our application. 
the results are returning back 3 dates which are:

```
a.) 'trackback_date'
b.) 'target_birth_date'
c.) 'firstpost_date'
```

i need to extract the time the tweet was done not sure which of these dates refer to that, whether they are the same or could be different in some case. Any link which explains the result field names with their actual meanings or at least help on the above.

Any help in this regard highly appreciated

Thanks 
Vaibhav

Answer (score 0):

You likely want trackback_date.

Consider the tweet:  https://twitter.com/vipulved/status/314803292356096000

If you searched for "non-native platforms", Topsy API will return the gothick.org.uk URL shared in the tweet.

The trackback date on the result will be the date of the tweet.

The target_birth_date will be the date of the first tweet ever that linked to gothick.org.uk URL.  This is a proxy for when the link was created.